# Is there an alternative for MS Project Server?

Tags: untagged

I have to use this pretty soon, and was wondering if there is an alternative to this. Preferably open source.

Comment: Product and service recommendations, including alternatives-recon, are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few alternatives, you should check out the following links to try to find one that is best suited for you:

http://www.pm-software.org/en/pm-software.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_project_management_software

I have tried MS Project (professional/sharepoint), dotProject, Trac and eGroupWare, but my favorite is probably Trac(http://trac.edgewall.org/).

Answer (score 1):

this is quite neat too.

tomsplanner.com

Comment: Looks really nice. I like the gantt chart, but an online service is not enough for this situation.

Comment: yea that is pretty cool.  I may have to check that out for my own stuff... but like saint said, not good enough for internal corporate stuff in my opinion.  cool for personal stuff though.

Answer (score 1):

I'll toss in Redmine. It's very similiar to Trac but is more flexible, and supports multiple projects which with Trac is a hassle. I will also say customizing the Redmine back-end has been only slightly painless the authors do a very good job at organization and layout even on the backend.

http://www.redmine.org/
Also for Trac or Redmine you might check out 
http://bitnami.org/

Answer (score 1):

RationalPlan is a good alternative to MS Project and there is also available a Server version for it:
http://www.rationalplan.com/server-project-management-software.php